# error: object sbtassembly is not a member of package <root>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have build.sbt file as below
`

```
import _root_.sbt.Keys._
 import _root_.sbt.Keys._
 import _root_.sbtassembly.Plugin.AssemblyKeys._
 import sbtassembly.Plugin.AssemblyKeys
 import AssemblyKeys._
```

`
while building the project i am getting below error

`error: object sbtassembly is not a member of package <root>
import _root_.sbtassembly.Plugin.AssemblyKeys._`

Can someone please help

Comment: plugin.sbt file is missing the below line causing the issue.

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")

Once i added the line. Issue got resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to bring in sbt-assembly in project/plugins.sbt
http://www.scalastyle.org/sbt.html

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for looking into it